# I need to count the lines from matching config file entries, preferably with 'grep'

Tags: awk, count, grep, aix

I have a configuration file that has entries for various devices, with each entry separated by a blank line.  I need to search the file for all instances of a given device type, and count the number of non-blank lines following the occurrence, stopping at the first blank.

For example:

> Server=foo
>   config line 1
>   config line 2
>   config line 3
>
> Server=bar
>   config line 1
>   config line 2
>
> Server=foo
>   config line 1

If I wanted to know how many total "config lines" were associated with server "foo", I should get four.  Can you please help?

I am on AIX 5.3. It doesn't have pcregrep. :( Grep, sed, and awk are all I have access to.

Answer (score 2):

This simple awk script will tell you information you need:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f    

$1 ~ /^Server=/ {
    server = $1;
}

($0 != "") && ($1 !~ /^Server=/) {
    count[server] += 1
}

END {
    for (server in count) {
        print server, count[server]
    }
}
```

You may need to adjust /usr/bin/awk path to match yours. If you place this code in `counter` script, it and invoke it like this:

```
./counter < config
```

It will output following for your example config:

```
Server=foo 4
Server=bar 2
```

If you need to get rid of Server= at the beginning of lines, you can pipe it through sed:

```
./counter < config | sed 's/^Server=//'
```